# iPhone dialog application startup during incoming voice call

Tags: iphone, ios4, call

Is it possible to start an application on the iPhone (iOS 4.x) when there is an incoming voice call? In other words, the incoming voice call should trigger the application startup.

In such a case the application should not be full-screen, but should cover only part of the screen to not hide the native controls for accepting or rejecting the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, at least by using documented API and apple approve way.

Comment: Hi, first thank you for you answer. Just one more thing - by saying "NO" you mean that both tasks are not possible, either application start-up as a result of the incoming voice call event and also making the application, which occupies only part screen is not possible (dialog like window)? Kind Regards

Comment: As far as I know, every app will fill up the full screen.